# Finding Fixed Point of the Coupled Differential Equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

```
 x'[t] == v[t]/ω,

 v'[t] == G/Q (2*BesselJ[1, v[t - τ]] + (α v[t] - 3/4 γ v[t]^3)) - ω*x[t] - v[t]/Q
```

Here

```
ω=2*pi*11.2*10^6, Q=70, G=2.5, α=1, γ=.06, τ=15
```

Once I obtain the fixed point is it possible to study the saddle node and Hopf bifurcation of this equation with parameter G and two parameter bifurcation with the parameter `G` and `\[Epsilon] = 1/Q`

Comment: How would you solve it with pen on paper? You need to carry out the same steps using Mathematica.  There is no builtin function that take a differential equation as input and gives you the fixed point as output.

Comment: It is trivially `x=v=0`.

Comment: Thank you Alexei Boulbitch .Can you please explain. There is Bessel term involved here so it may have other fixed points.

Comment: `x'[t] == 0` iff `v[t] == 0`. Then `FullSimplify[r.h.s. of v'[t] /. {v[t] -> 0, v[t - τ] -> 0}]` gives `v'[t] = -ω x[t]`, which is zero iff `x[t] == 0`. So the only equilibrium is at `{x[t], v[t]} == {0, 0}`. `BesselJ` doesn't change anything because `BesselJ[1, 0] == 0`.

Comment: Thank you very much